# enable sharding policies in Spring rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Is there a way I can define sharding policy for RabbitMQ exchanges using Spring AMQP? Any research I have done on this has not provided me with an answer.

The problem I am facing is as below:

I defined a direct exchange in Spring as below:

rabbit:direct-exchange id="pb" name="test.pb" durable="true"

Then created a policy for the same for sharding:

rabbitmqctl set_policy pbmodule-shard "^test.pb$" "{""shards-per-node"": "3", ""routing-key"": ""bill""}"

After this I send the message:

this.rabbitTemplate.send("test.pb", "bill", message);

What I saw was that the message was delivered to all the 3 sharded queues. Shouldn't it be delivered to only one?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking; sharding is configured on the broker and the client is oblivious to it.

Comment: @GaryRussell, thanks for responding. I edited my post to add more information.

Comment: RabbitMQ recommendation is to use the x-modulus-hash exchange, but I am unsure as to how this is configured using Spring-Rabbit

Comment: Fixed it using a custom exchange as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141955/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange-with-java-client-spring-rabbit

Comment: You can answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: SO just converts an answer to a comment if its a one liner